# problems in using telnet.expect in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am trying to telnet to remote server and trying to get the response back.

I was using `telnet.read_until` earlier to match whether prompt/pattern appeared or not but read_until returns everything even if there is no match. I thought of using `telnet.expect` but i am getting error

Below is the code

```
com = re.compile("\#") # is the prompt
tn.write("somecommand" + "\n")
res = tn.expect(com, 10)
```

Error I am getting is

```
  File "reg.txt", line 23, in login
    res = tn.expect(com, 10)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 593, in expect
    list = list[:]
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`telnetlib.expect()` requires `list` as first argument, you are giving a `SRE_pattern`.

From [telnetlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.expect):

> Telnet.expect(list, timeout=None)
>
> Read until one from a list of a regular expressions matches.
>
> The first argument is a list of regular expressions, either compiled (regex objects) or uncompiled (byte strings). The optional second argument is a timeout, in seconds; the default is to block indefinitely.
>
> [...]

---

```
com = re.compile("\#") # is the prompt
tn.write("somecommand" + "\n")
res = tn.expect([com], 10)
```

Should works (*the diff is `expect([com])` instead of `expect(com)`*).